# jQuery - Easiest way to pull multiple .(val) into one string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given an unknown number of dynamically produced  text inputs:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numInputs2Render; i++) {
    collectEmails = collectEmails + '<input type="text" id="Email' + i + '" name="Email' + i + '">';
}
```

I need to produce a comma delimited string of the combined input values. Does jQuery give me a one-step solution or will i need to iterate and manually construct the string? (if if manually...how's that look?)

thx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
var emails = $("input[name^=Email]").map(function() { return this.value; })
                                   .get().join(',');
```

This uses the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to find the inputs, then [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the values into an array you can [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) into a single string.

If they're in a container, say a `<div id="Emails">` you could slim the selector down to something like `$("#Emails input")`, I can't say for sure without seeing your markup, but anything with a container selector will make it more efficient.

Comment: @Felix - Agreed, or if we had a bit more context, they're probably all in a single container given how they're being generated.

Comment: Indeed - i pulled the 'class=emailInput' from the OP for sake of brevity. How would that change the answer? - very much appreciated!

Comment: @justSteve - Just use `$(".emailInput")` for your selector :)